# Can a class library project be added to a solution as Read Only in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a situation where a number of Solutions contain projects which use the same class library. I would like the class library code to only be able to be changed in the one of these solutions (so that we have a tight control over changes to the library). However we also would like to be able to debug code in the solutions which use the library so we may need to step through the library code to find bugs. Is this possible? And if so how?

Comment: It sounds like a simpler solution would be to require that code builds (and, ideally, passes tests) when committing to source control.  Rather than trying to prevent developers from changing code (yes, that's intended to make the idea sound silly), provide them with tools and automation which helps them more effectively change code.  Sometimes developers commit breaking changes.  It happens.  Historically it's a *lot* easier and more meaningful to respond to that event than to try to prevent it.

Comment: I know, but different teams will be responsible for the library code than the other applications. Also this is very very old code and has not tests written for it, plus there is no budget or time at the moment to re-write the code or to write tests. It works (just about) so it will be staying like that for at least the next year.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we do this.

The idea is to give different accesses for different people working via TFS (Team Foundation Service).

Some employees have access to one source code, and others only have read-only access, so they can add a refference of the code but they cannot commit any changes to it.

The best approach, I believe, is to use a source control system, like the one I mentioned: TFS, and define this hierarchy.

The only thing to be aware is that even if the guy is going to have a readonly access, he/she can effectively read the code. In some cases we just want to provide a set of APIs, protecting the code from undesired access.

Hope I have answered your question.

Comment: We do not have TFS, however we do use Mercurial, We may have team members moving about a bit so it may be a bit too hard to limit each user as sometimes they may need access via the correct solution to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an internal NuGet repository for the library, then just update this NuGet repository via the team that's responsible.  You can also host an internal source server using SymbolSource community version to debug into the source if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have been a bit dumb here. Obviously the answer is to simply reference debug versions of the dll along with its pdb file. That way we can debug the code but not alter it. If a bug is then found in the dll then this can be passed to the team responsible.